# DRV8871 Motor driver bulk capacitance value

Tags: motordriver

I am designing a HVAC control panel for 4 wheeler. In my design I am using 4 DRV8871-Q1.
The motor ratings are:

- Type = Brushed DC motor
- Operating Voltage = 9-16V DC
- Nominal Voltage = 12V DC
- Nominal Load Current <= 150 mA
- No Load Current = 50 mA
- Stall Current <= 400 mA

[image: schematic]

[image: PCB]

I am using four 47uF 35V electrolytic bulk capacitors which increases the overall price of the product.

My question is that can I use smaller value of bulk capacitor maybe of 0.1uF or 0.47uF ceramic cap, as it is already in the circuit design and is much cheaper.

Comment: Have you simulated it with different capacitor values, especially with a load step/start/stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of bulk capacitor is like reservor for inrush current from driving load just like bypass capacitor.
The result of absent or too low capacitant is voltage ripple due to current draw .
[image]

This effect came form inductance of power wire and ESR of power source and load's current behavior.

So it possible to reduce to buck capacitor value but you need to verify on the real system and do some work around like minimize the length of power line, use high current capabillity power source, etc.

Honestly just use the bulk capacitor that recommended. 47 uF is very reasonable value to use. The preblems that came after might need more money to fixed than a capacitor price.